# Is there a curved EdgeShapeFunction that has arrowheads?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

The undocumented `"CurvedArc"` [`EdgeShapeFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeShapeFunction.html) draws edges as curves (instead of straight lines). However, it does not draw arrowheads for directed graphs.

Is there a *built-in* `EdgeShapeFunction` specification that draws directed edges as curved arcs, with a consistent curve direction relative to the edge direction, and visible arrowheads?

I could certainly create my own edge shape function that does this. But this is such a frequently needed edge shape function that I am hoping that it is already built in, just not documented (just like "CurvedArc").

---

Example of a graph where this would be useful, and CurvedArc fails.

```
RelationGraph[MemberQ[{1, 2, 4}, Mod[#1 - #2, 7]] &, Range[0, 6],
 EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedArc"]
```

[image]

Note that this is a directed graph.

Edge shape function that would work better with this graph:

```
rot[{x_, y_}] := {-y, x}
arc = Function[{pts, edge},
  Module[{s = First[pts], t = Last[pts]},
   {Arrowheads[{{Automatic, 2/3}}], 
    Arrow@BezierCurve[{s, s + (t - s)/2 + 1/8 rot[t - s] , t}]}
   ]
  ]
```

All edge shape function specs should be listed by `GraphElementData["EdgeShapeFunction"]` but they aren't.

Comment: In v12, `GraphLayout -> "GravityEmbedding"` does this (despite a layout having no business of changing edge shapes...) I just don't know which edge shape spec it uses.

Comment: I went so far as to run `strings` on the kernel library, but unfortunately the edge shape functions aren't clustered near each other so it's too much effort to try and come up with a real list. If it helps, `CurvedArc` and `CurvedEdge` are the only two I could find that weren't in the list.

Comment: `TracePrint` + `MakeBoxes` on a graph with `GraphLayout -> "GravityEmbedding"` shows it's using `"CurvedEdge"`.

Comment: @ChipHurst In that case, there must be a sub-option to CurvedEdge that adds the arrowheads. I know I can do `Show[g] /. bc_BezierCurve :> Arrow[bc]` but that is ugly and makes a Graphics not a Graph

Comment: I might not be understanding the question correctly. Can't you just do `RelationGraph[MemberQ[{1, 2, 4}, Mod[#1 - #2, 7]] &, Range[0, 6], 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedEdge"]`?

Comment: @ChipHurst I am sorry, I misread your comment. You are saying that I should use CurvedEdge and not CurvedArc. Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. Please post an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can check if `Graph` calls `GraphElementData` during the drawing stage:

```
With[{g = Graph[{1 -> 2}, GraphLayout -> "GravityEmbedding"]},
 TracePrint[MakeBoxes[g], _GraphElementData, TraceInternal -> True]
];
```

> ```
> GraphElementData[CurvedEdge]
>
>    GraphElementData[{CurvedEdge,0.0183437}]
> ```

And so:

```
RelationGraph[MemberQ[{1, 2, 4}, Mod[RandomChoice[{Abs, Identity}][#1 - #2], 7]] &, 
  Range[0, 6], EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedEdge"]
```

[image]

Comment: For reference, this solution works only in M12.0 or later.